# ActiveRecord execute raw sql not returning any results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "SELECT sometable.* from sometable limit 10"
   (76.1ms)  SELECT sometable.* from sometable limit 10
=> #<PG::Result:0x007fbd99647608
 @connection=
  #<PG::Connection:0x007fbd9ac05fa8
   @notice_processor=nil,
   @notice_receiver=nil,
   @socket_io=nil>>
```

Not sure why no results are returned. There is definitely an active connection and I am able to query the database with normal ActiveRecord query interface. But when I switch to raw sql I get the above problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Mysql2::Result` or `PG::Result` object has a `each` method to iterate through results

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT sometable.* from sometable limit 10").each |row|
  p row
end
```

**Note**: You cannot access the results like array. Need to use `each` method

```
 array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT sometable.* from sometable limit 10")
 array[0] # This will not work
```

Try `select_all` if you want results in `Array`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all "SELECT sometable.* from sometable limit 10"
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the result returned from a postgresql database: the PostGresResult. (Hence the "PG)  The pg gem is how you connect with the database. [Here's the wiki for the PG gem.](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home)
The 'pg' gem doc (and related libpg) gives all of the exciting details about the nitty-gritty of interacting with a Postgresql db.

`PG::PGResult` is now referred to as `PG::Result`. [The documentation for PG::Result is here.](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Result)

@shiva is right: For Postgres, the results aren't an Array.  (Other databases apparently do return Arrays from these calls). But the `PG::Result` class has methods for iterating through each row, converting to a Hash, and more.  (That's what @shiva was alluding to.)  Check out the documentation link above.

You may need to put `require 'pg'` in your specific source file, depending on how you have your project & development environment set up.  (Since you can connect to the database, you already have the pg gem installed.)

Here's the overview and an example from the `PG::Result` documentation page:

> `PG::Result` (alias = `PGResult`)
>
> The class to represent the query result tuples (rows). An instance of
>   this class is created as the result of every query. You may need to
>   invoke the #clear method of the instance when finished with the result
>   for better memory performance.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> require 'pg'
> conn = PGconn.open(:dbname => 'test')
> res  = conn.exec('SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, NULL AS c')
> res.getvalue(0,0) # '1'
> res[0]['b']       # '2'
> res[0]['c']       # nil
> ```

Just to illuminate the example a bit:

The example above returns one row (index = 0) with three columns. The first column is 'a'; there is another column called 'b' and the third column is called 'c'. You can get the value for the first column of the first row as:

```
res.getvalue(0,0)
```

and it will return the value '1'

You can get the value for the second column of the first row as:

```
res[0]['b']
```

and it will return the value '2'

The third line of the example uses the same approach to get the value of column 'c' for the first row (which returns a value of `nil`).

Of course you can use the more readable methods in `PG::Result`